# How to have multiple host property values on filebeat configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, amazon-ecs, filebeat

The filebeat `yaml` configuration file have this `hosts` property. So this host property is an array. This filebeat will be running on ECS and I want to get the hosts property value/s from environmental variables. How can get Array from environmental variables and assign it `hosts` variable?

for Example:

This is ECS task definition

```
task_definition:
  container_definitions:
    - name: your-container
      environment:
        - name: ARR_VAR
          value: [value1,value2,value3]
```

Below from filebeat config

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: [value1, value2,value3]
```